# mxml modules and variables visibility

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mxml

Consider the following code

```
<fx:Script source="Script.as" />
......................
<s:Group>
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Spacer width="10" />
    <s:Button label="1" click="doSomething()"/>
    <s:Button label="2" click="holder.getCanvas().testDraw()"/>
    <s:Button label="3" click="doSomething()"/>
</s:Group>
<s:Scroller id="canvasGroup" width="650" height="500">
    <s:Group>
        <local:CanvasHolder id="canvas" />
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

I want to move buttons in a separate module (let's call it `Toolbar.mxml`). Thus I'll need to move `<fx:Script source="Script.as" />` (in `Script.as` I use canvas as well). Here's my questions:

1. How can I see `canvas` var in `Toolbar.mxml` (and can I)?
2. Is it possible somehow to pu `<fx:Script source="Script.as" />` so that it could be seen from `Toolbar.mxml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You won't be able to automatically "see" `canvas` in `Toolbar.mxml`. I would recommend using Flex's Event architecture to access it.

   ```
   //Extend Event class to hold any data that must be passed
   //from Toolbar -> canvas
   public class CustomEvent extends Event
   {
       public static const CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "CustomEventTypeString";
       public var mImportantInfo:String = "";

       public function CustomEvent();
       {
           super(CUSTOM_EVENT);
       }

       override public function clone():Event
       {
           var evt:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent();
           evt.mImportantInfo = mImportantInfo;
           return evt;
       }
   }

   //in Script.as
   myToolbarID.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT,customEventHandler);
   ...
   protected function customEventHandler(var evt:CustomEvent)
   {
       canvas.myFunction(evt.mImportantInfo);
   }

   //in Toolbar.mxml
   var evt:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent();
   evt.mImportantInfo = "canvas needs me!";
   dispatchEvent(evt);
   ```

   Alternatively, you can pass the canvas object to the Toolbar directly.

   ```
   <local:Toolbar ... myCanvas="{canvas}" ... />

   //in Toolbar.mxml
   public var myCanvas:CanvasHolder;
   ...
   myCanvas.myFunction(...);
   ```

   Yes, the second option is much simpler, but the first option is often useful when the components that need to talk aren't easy to pass to each other.
2. You can put `<fx:Script source="Script.as" />` *in* `Toolbar.mxml`, if that's what you need. If you need to call functions in the scope of the parent, I would recommend using the Event architecture again, as opposed to some kind of `parent...` or `Application.application...` call.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to understand what you are doing is to compile with `-keep` option - this will generate the actual AS3 code compiled from MXML templates.

Let's say that using `<Script source="script.as"/>` is not a good approach - this is identical to doing `include "script.as"` in AS3 - IDEs don't like it, and, in general, it's a clutter. If you need the "code behind", just write it first in AS3 and then extend your AS3 class in MXML.

Another important thing to understand - every time you use `id` attribute in MXML template results in the generated class having a public property with the name which is the value of `id` attribute. So, if you move some part of your code outside the class (or MXML template) where you declared that property - you  will go about it just the same way as you would with AS3 classes - `objectWithTheProperty.property`.